# Subtrair horas php

Tags: php

Preciso subtrair as horas e não sei como fazer. As variáveis passam de 24hr.

```
$hora1 = "78:00";
$hora2 = "22:00";
$tempo = $hora1 - $hora2;

resultado 56:00
```

Como subtrair isso?

Comment: Qual o resultado desejado?

Comment: editei a pergunta. @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Você gostaria que o resultado fosse qual valor? @smourao

Comment: o valor é variante, é de acordo com o que for cadastrado na tabela, tipo somo todas as entradas e subtraio todas as saidas e me retorna um valor (26:00hrs), mas fiz isso direto no sql. Com php não tô conseguindo. @AndréFilipe

Comment: @smourao o formato da hora sempre será o mesmo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não confunda **horário** com **quantidade de horas**. O que você tem são quantidades de horas e minutos, separados por dois pontos, o que te induzirá a achar que é um horário. E para subtrair quantidades, basta ter dois valores numéricos.

O mais fácil é converter as duas quantidades para uma só, de minutos totais, subtrair entre elas e após converter de volta para horas e minutos; isso evitará o problema de subtrair, por exemplo 10:00 e 09:30 ficando 1 hora e -30 minutos, que não faz muito sentido. Assim:

```
list($horas, $minutos) = explode(':', '78:00');
$minutosTotais1 = $horas * 60 + $minutos;

list($horas, $minutos) = explode(':', '22:00');
$minutosTotais2 = $horas * 60 + $minutos;

$minutosDiferenca = $minutosTotais1 - $minutosTotais2;

$horas = intdiv($minutosDiferenca, 60);
$minutos = $minutosDiferenca % 60;

echo "Diferença de {$horas}:{$minutos}", PHP_EOL;
```

A saída seria `Diferença de 56:0`. Você pode forçar que a saída seja com dois zeros, `56:00`, através da função `str_pad`.

Comment: obrigado, salvou meu dia.